# can an "owner" lock RAM?

Tags: ram

I've been reading http://www.ccs.neu.edu/course/com3200/parent/NOTES/DDR.html

and it seems to suggest that a closed page cannot be accessed by anything other than the owner, paraphrasing.

Is this true?  If not, how can RAM be locked, if at all?

Comment: I cannot find the word "lock" or "owner" anywhere in that page.

Comment: @Kaz i was paraphrasing.  there are "States [that] (must not be interrupted by any command)", and I'm assuming that that means the controller (& possibly processor) are in a closed circuit that if interrupted would cause a crash

Comment: But that has nothing to do with what an operating system calls a "page" or "ownership". What exactly do you mean by "locked" when applied to RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dram as implemented can't be locked per se.  What that sentence means is that if you interrupt the process or interfere with it, the results are uncertain and may end up in corrupted memory.  There is nothing preventing you fro m messing with the memory locations so be careful.